# Is There Solution For Auto Delete Image From Project

Tags: database, image, github, directory, store

I create a project in java netbeans using swing form. I add image in JLabel from my device folder. But if i delete that image from my device than also delete from my Project. Is there any other solution for this problem ?

If it is posssible to fetch data from url or github account and database also..

Answer (score -1):

When working with a Java Swing project in NetBeans and adding images to a JLabel from a local device folder, there is a concern that deleting the image from the device folder will also remove it from the project. However, there is a solution to address this issue.

To prevent the image from being dependent on the device folder, you can embed the image within your Java project. Follow these steps:

1.Create a new folder within your Java project, such as "resources" or "images."
2.Copy the image file into this folder.
3.In NetBeans, right-click on your project and select "Properties."
4.Go to the "Sources" category in the Project Properties dialog.
5.Click on the "Add Folder" button and select the folder where you copied the image.
6.Click "OK" to close the dialog.
Now, you can reference the image file from your code using the relative path within your project.
following is the example1:

```
String imagePath = "resources/image.jpg"; // Replace "image.jpg" with the actual filename
URL imageUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imagePath);
if (imageUrl != null) {
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageUrl);
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    // Add the label to your Swing form or perform further operations
} else {
    // Handle the case where the image file is not found
}
```

following code snippet loads an image file named "image.jpg" from the "resources" folder within your project. It uses getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() to obtain the URL of the image file. If the image file is found, an ImageIcon is created and assigned to a JLabel, which can then be added to your Swing form or used for other operations. In case the image file is not found, you can handle the situation in the else block. I hope this helps.